# How to match a string pattern in python

Tags: python, pattern-matching

I am looking to match a pattern such as

```
(u'-<21 characters>', N),
```

21 character of 0-9, a-z, A-Z plus characters like ~!@#$%^&*()_ ...
N is a number from 1 to 99

I am trying to find the specific way to retrieve the 21 characters as well as the number N and use them later on using the `re.match` method but I do not know how and the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) is not understandable. How do I do so?

Comment: possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300020/python-match-a-string-with-regex

Comment: Your question is not really clear... What is the data you have at the moment. Should the pattern you describe be the input or the output of your function ?

Comment: @DrBwts - I don't think that's a good dup -- This post is asking about groups, and that post doesn't involve groups in any way.

Comment: Does your data string *only* consist of 21 characters and a single number separated by a comma?  Or is that pattern embedded inside a larger string?  Could you supply example input data and expected output please?

Comment: @LoicM I have a .txt file filled with such lines ((u'-<21 characters>', N),\n)
I wish for each line to retrieve the 21 characters as well as the Number, so it'd be the output.

Comment: @cdarke e.g. (part of the file)
`(u'--UE_y6auTgq3FXlvUMkbw', 10),
(u'--XBxRlD92RaV6TyUnP8Ow', 1),
(u'--sSW-WY3vyASh_eVPGUAw', 2),
(u'-0GkcDiIgVm0XzDZC8RFOg', 9),
(u'-0OlcD1Ngv3yHXZE6KDlnw', 1),
(u'-0QBrNvhrPQCaeo7mTo0zQ', 1),`

Comment: So a simple split around a comma could suffice?

Comment: @cdarke I have 1 comma after the string of 21 chars and 1 comma after each line, before the '\n'. Plus I need to get rid of the `(u'` part as well as the closing parenthesis in the end of each line.

Comment: The data you just posted, is that one line or is each parentheses group on a separate line?

Comment: I did say possible duplicate, to be honest it was difficult to work out what was being asked

Comment: You say "21 character of 0-9, a-z, A-Z ".  The line `u'--UE_y6auTgq3FXlvUMkbw'`, after the `--` it is only 20 chars, and it includes an `_`, so should that not match?  Also, `u'--sSW-WY3vyASh_eVPGUAw'` includes a `-` and a `_`, so should that not match either?

Comment: @cdarke no, each data is on a different line; the copying-pasting must have ruined that.
Also yes, edited to be fixed; it can have other characters as well.

Comment: @DrBwts the other question, despite the title, is **not about regex at all**. I just finished closing it as a duplicate of other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one program that might do what you want.

Note the use of parentheses `()` to isolate the data you are looking for. Note also the use of `m.group(1)`, `m.group(2)` to retrieve those saved items.

Note also the use of `re.search()` instead of `re.match()`. `re.match()` must match the data from the very beginning of the string. `re.search()`, on the other hand, will find the first match, regardless of its location in the string. (But also consider using `re.findall()`, if a string might have multiple matches.).

Don't be confused by my use of `.splitlines()`, it is just for the sake of the sample program. You could equally well do `data = open('foo.txt')` / `for line in data:`.

```
import re

data = '''
(u'--UE_y6auTgq3FXlvUMkbw', 10),
(u'--XBxRlD92RaV6TyUnP8Ow', 1),
(u'--sSW-WY3vyASh_eVPGUAw', 2),
(u'-0GkcDiIgVm0XzDZC8RFOg', 9),
(u'-0OlcD1Ngv3yHXZE6KDlnw', 1),
(u'-0QBrNvhrPQCaeo7mTo0zQ', 1)
'''
data = data.splitlines()

for line in data:
    m = re.search(r"'(.+)', (\d+)", line)
    if m:
        chars = m.group(1)
        N = int(m.group(2))
        print("I found a match!: {}, {}".format(chars, N))
```

Comment: This does print each line, thank you. I can use chars and N to store the pairs each time right?

Comment: Yes, `chars` and `N` will hold, for each iteration of the loop, the values you want. If you want all of the different `chars, N` pairs, you might want to create a list to hold them all.