# How to filter command line output?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to filter the output of a command executed in network equipment in order to bring only the lines that match a text like '10.13.32.34'.
I created a python code that brings all the output of the command but I need only part of this.

I am using Python 3.7.3 running on a Windows 10 Pro.

The code I used is below and I need the filtering part because I am a network engineer without the basic notion of python programming. (till now...)

```
from steelscript.steelhead.core import steelhead
from steelscript.common.service import UserAuth
auth = UserAuth(username='admin', password='password')
sh = steelhead.SteelHead(host='em01r001', auth=auth)
from steelscript.cmdline.cli import CLIMode
sh.cli.exec_command("show connections optimized", mode=CLIMode.CONFIG)
output = (sh.cli.exec_command("show connections optimized"))
```

Comment: Have you checked something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19300020/python-match-a-string-with-regex

Comment: Also perhaps it is not a good idea to display username and password in clear text..

Comment: can you print the output of the `output`? then we can make some regex to match your IP address.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your output looks like, so used the text in your question as example data. Anyway, for a simple pattern such as what's shown in your question, you could do it like this:

```
output = '''\
I need to filter the output of a command executed
in network equipment in order to bring only the
lines that match a text like '10.13.32.34'. I
created a python code that brings all the output
of the command but I need only part of this.

I am using Python 3.7.3 running on a Windows 10
Pro.

The code I used is below and I need the filtering
part because I am a network engineer without the
basic notion of python programming. (till now...)
'''

# Filter the lines of text in output.
filtered = ''.join(line for line in output.splitlines()
                            if '10.13.32.34' in line)

print(filtered)  # -> lines that match a text like '10.13.32.34'. I
```

You could do something similar for more complex patterns by using the [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match) function in Python's built-in regular expression [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#module-re) module. Using regular expressions is more complicated, but extremely powerful. There are many tutorials on using them, including one in Python's own documentation titled the [Regular Expression HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html).